# Grepping for text in images

Tags: python, image

I built a small wrapper script around pytesseract, that lets you

- check if an image contains some text, or pattern
- look for images, that contain some text, or pattern

## High Level Approach

I get the image text with `pytesseract.image_to_string(img)`, and then compare against the user supplied regex with `pattern.search(text)` (pattern being a normal `re.Pattern` object).

## Usage

The usage is meant to mimick `grep`, but there's obviously a lot missing. Some things, like `-a`, `-b` and `-v` are planned for the future, but not included for now.

```
usage: imgrep [-h] [-i] [-r] [-f] [-0] pattern file

Grep for text in images.

positional arguments:
  pattern               A Python regex, to search for.
  file                  Path of the image(s) to search through. (Or folder(s),
                        if `--recursive' is specified).

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i, --ignore-case     Ignore case distinctions in patterns and input data.
  -r, --recursive       Grep through every file under a given directory.
  -f, --filenames-only  Only print the file names, not the contents. Makes no
                        sense without `--recursive', and will be ignored if
                        `--recursive' is not specified.
  -0, --null            Print the output seperated by null characters, this is
                        useful for badly named files. Makes no sense without
                        `--filenames-only', but will be done regardless, if
                        specified!

Be patient. It uses multiple cores, but this just takes a while. Searching for
a specific string in my ca. 2000 image strong memes folder took about 8
minutes and 30 seconds.
```

## Code

```py
import argparse
import re

from typing import List, Union
from pathlib import Path
from multiprocessing import Pool
from os import cpu_count
from functools import partial

import PIL
import pytesseract


def parse_args(argv=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Grep for text in images.')

    parser.add_argument('pattern', type=str, help='A Python regex, to search for.')
    parser.add_argument('file', type=Path,
                        help='Path of the image(s) to search through. (Or folder(s), if `--recursive\' is specified).')

    parser.add_argument('-i', '--ignore-case', action='store_true',
                        help='Ignore case distinctions in patterns and input data.')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--recursive', action='store_true',
                        help='Grep through every file under a given directory.')
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--filenames-only', action='store_true',
                        help='Only print the file names, not the contents.\nMakes no sense without `--recursive\', '
                             'and will be ignored if `--recursive\' is not specified.')
    parser.add_argument('-0', '--null', action='store_true',
                        help='Print the output seperated by null characters, this is useful for badly named files.\n'
                             'Makes no sense without `--filenames-only\', but will be done regardless, if specified!')

    parser.epilog = f'Be patient. It uses multiple cores, but this just takes a while.\n' \
                    f'Searching for a specific string in my ca. 2000 image strong memes folder took about 8 minutes ' \
                    f'and 30 seconds.'

    return parser.parse_args() if argv is None else parser.parse_args(argv)


def imgrep(image: Union[str, Path], needle: re.Pattern) -> List[str]:
    try:
        img = PIL.Image.open(image)
    except PIL.UnidentifiedImageError:
        # skip in case PIL cannot decode the file for any reason
        # (e.g. it might not even be image data)
        return []

    haystack: str = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    return [line for line in haystack.splitlines() if needle.search(line)]


def recurse(directory: Union[str, Path], needle: re.Pattern, filenames_only: bool = False) -> List[str]:
    output = []

    dir = Path(directory)
    files = [file for file in dir.glob('**/*') if file.is_file()]

    with Pool() as pool:
        f = partial(imgrep, needle=needle)
        chunksize = len(files) // (cpu_count() * 4) if len(files) > (cpu_count() * 4) else 1
        results = pool.map(f, files, chunksize=chunksize)

    for hits, file in zip(results, files):
        if hits:
            if filenames_only:
                output.append(str(file))
            else:
                output.append(f'{file}: ')
                output.extend(hits)

    return output


def main(argv=None):
    args = parse_args() if argv is None else parse_args(argv)

    recursive: bool = args.recursive
    ignore_case: bool = args.ignore_case
    filenames_only: bool = args.filenames_only
    null: bool = args.null

    pattern: re.Pattern = re.compile(args.pattern) if not ignore_case else re.compile(args.pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
    file: Path = args.file

    if not file.exists():
        print(f'{file} does not exist, or is not readable.')
        exit(1)

    if not recursive:
        if file.is_dir():
            print(f'{file} is a directory. Try again with `--recursive\'')
            exit(2)
    else:
        if not file.is_dir():
            print(f'{file} is not a directory. Try again without `--recursive\'')
            exit(3)

    output = imgrep(file, pattern) if not recursive else recurse(file, pattern, filenames_only)

    for line in output:
        print(line, end='\0' if null else '\n')

    exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Concerns

What I'm mostly concerned about is the way I handle the arguments, and where the logic resides. There are not so many right now, that it would be a problem, but since I'm thinking about adding some for various things in the future this seems problematic.

For example, while I do think, it makes sense to handle the `-0`, `-r` and `-i` options outside the actual functions (`recurse` and `imgrep`), it does not make sense for the `-f` option, or `-a` and `-b` options, that I want to add.

This and the argument validation seem a little ugly to me, but honestly, I don't know what I would do differently.

Comments regarding improvements of command line options, and general usage are also appreciated.

The whole project can be found at [GitHub](https://github.com/FynnFreyer/imgrep/tree/8c6f2419ed767107766cbe1d095c30d389623e0d), if you want to comment on the packaging and/or CI/CD approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall I think this is pretty nice code.

#### Make the UX more friendly

It's an error when:

- the specified path is a directory and `--recursive` is not used
- the specified path is a file and `--recursive` is used

Although the usage message helpfully tells what to do (add or drop `--recursive`),
it would be simpler to decide the right action depending on whether the path is a directory or not.
Simpler for users and for the implementation too.

But you make a good point in a comment that recursive grep is a CPU intensive operation, and the `--recursive` flag serves as a safeguard.
That makes sense, and the UNIX `grep` utility does this too.
On the other hand, `grep` doesn't complain when `--recursive` is present and the path argument is a file.
Maybe that could be a good middle ground.

#### Separate concerns

The `main` function performs:

- additional validation of command line arguments
- call the right function to execute the main task
- output results

It would be good to move the implemnentations to separate functions.

#### Where to keep the validation logic?

I think you raise a very important concern here:

> What I'm mostly concerned about is the way I handle the arguments, and where the logic resides. There are not so many right now, that it would be a problem, but since I'm thinking about adding some for various things in the future this seems problematic.

To phrase it differently,
the arguments returned by `argparse` are sometimes not fully validated,
raw low level configuration values,
which need further transformations to be useful,
such as the processing of a raw string pattern into a compiled regex.

I think it's a good idea to create a dedicated abstract data type to capture higher level configuration values,
using vocubulary that makes sense to the implementation.
Consider for example:

```
@dataclass
class Params:
    pattern: re.Pattern
    path: Path
    filenames_only: bool
    use_null_terminator: bool


def validated_params(argv=None) -> Params:
    if argv is None:
        args = parse_args()
    else:
        args = parse_args(argv)

    path = Path(args.file)
    if not path.exists():
        print(f'{path} does not exist, or is not readable.')
        exit(1)

    if args.ignore_case:
        pattern = re.compile(args.pattern, re.IGNORECASE)
    else:
        pattern = re.compile(args.pattern)

    return Params(
        pattern=pattern,
        path=path,
        filenames_only=args.filenames_only,
        use_null_terminator=args.null
    )


def main(argv=None):
    params = validated_params(argv)

    # ...
```

#### Use better names

The names are pretty good, but I have some ideas:

- `dir` shadows a built-in, `basedir` or `path` would be better
- `file` can be a directory or a file, so `path` would work better
- `recurse` doesn't describe itself well. How about `imgrep_dirs` or `recursive_imgrep`.
- `null` as a variable name puts me off a little because it's a keyword in many other languages.
  And it doesn't describe well its purpose, so I'd just spell it out as `use_null_terminator`.

#### Don't repeat yourself

It's not a big problem, but there is some duplication here:

> ```
> chunksize = len(files) // (cpu_count() * 4) if len(files) > (cpu_count() * 4) else 1
> ```

A simpler way to the same effect:

```
chunksize = max(1, len(files) // (cpu_count() * 4))
```

#### Use stricter types

I don't see why `imgrep` and `recurse` both expect `Union[str, Path]` parameter.
It seems they are only called with `Path`,
so that would be a more appriate and at the same time simpler signature.

#### Streaming the output

Instead of collecting results in a list,
I think it would be better to *yield* them:

- To save memory
- To show results as the come in, rather than waiting until the end of processing all files

Comment: With the first point you mean I should silently recurse through the dir if a dir is passed and just look at that file alone if it's a file? Not sure about that, because I don't want to kick of a very CPU intense job, just because someone left a file name on accident. Grep also complains if youpass a dir but no `-r`

Comment: The rest though is very good advice! (And with the first one it's just my preference). Especially the yield and the params, so thank you for the great answer

Comment: Thanks @Fynn, I think your point makes sense. I amended the first point accordingly.

Comment: Overall I agree. Specific to _processing of a raw string pattern into a compiled regex_, there is an established pattern for that: pass a parser function ref to the [type argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type). This works well for regexes, files (`open`), primitives like `int`, etc.